# Does C# 4 optimize away namespaces in a manner that previous C# versions did not?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, namespaces

This question is for interest sake.  I'm working with a third-party library and came across the following documentation on a `CMS.Security.Dummy` class:

> DO NOT DELETE THIS CLASS - This class prevents the compiler from
>   dropping entire namespace under .NET 4.0.

Does anybody know, or can anybody speculate why .NET 4 would drop the namespace if the dummy class were removed?

Because .NET 4 is explicitly named in the source code comment, I assume previous C# versions exhibit behaviour that do not require this dummy class. That's purely speculative though.

**Screen shot**

[image: documentation]

**Decompiled Source Code**

```
#region Assembly CMS.SettingsProvider.dll, v4.0.30319
// ...\solution\wwwroot\Bin\CMS.SettingsProvider.dll
#endregion

using System;

namespace CMS.Security
{
    // Summary:
    //     DO NOT DELETE THIS CLASS - This class prevents the compiler from dropping
    //     entire namespace under .NET 4.0.
    public class Dummy
    {
        // Summary:
        //     DO NOT DELETE THIS CLASS - This class prevents the compiler from dropping
        //     entire namespace under .NET 4.0.
        public Dummy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see if there's anything like that in the pre-.NET 4.0 version of the library.

Comment: IIRC namespaces do not exist in CIL as separate entities -- they simply become part of qualified type names. (AFAIK that is true for all versions of the CLI and not specific to .NET 4.) In this sense I would support @Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: A nice question raised by a suspicious requirement :)

Comment: Now it would be interesting to know why the library (thinks it) needs the namespace …

Comment: Do you have a support line back to the library author?  In the face of Eric's answer I'm curious what they think they're accomplishing with that.

Comment: Chances are the 3rd party source has using statements that refer to this namespace. This hack is likely there so that they don't have to update their source, or less likely, maintain backward compatibility with clients that also have dependencies on that namespace.

Comment: @bryanbcook: I guess you mean the [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) — not the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)...

Answer (score 90, accepted):

A little-appreciated fact is that there is no such thing as a "namespace" from the point of view of the underlying CLR type system. Rather, it's just a *convention* that we say that a type that contains periods in its name is "a member of a namespace". *Logically* there is no difference at all between the legal code:

```
namespace N
{
    class C  {}
}
```

and the psuedo-code:

```
class N.C {}
```

C# forces you to pretend this pleasant fiction is reality, but it is just a fiction -- *from the perspective of the CLR type system,* of course. From the perspective of the C# compiler, of course namespaces are "real". They just don't correspond to anything in metadata other than a portion of the name of a type.

In short: if you make an assembly with an "empty" namespace then the "namespace" doesn't exist at all in the compiled binary. A "namespace" only comes into existence when there is a type in the library that has periods in its name.

Now, why you would care about ensuring that an "empty" namespace has some presence in the binary form, I have no idea.

> I assume previous C# versions exhibit behaviour that do not require this dummy class

Nope. Every version of C# since 1.0 throws away empty namespaces.

Comment: I would assume the reason they care about having an empty namespace is because they reference it in using statements elsewhere.  If the namespace didn't exist, that using statement would be a compile-time error.  Why not simply delete the using statements?  It could be the output of some code generation tool they have no control over.  (At least, this is the situation where I've encountered this before.)

Answer (score 23):

Given that the namespace doesn't contain any members (without that class), I'm not sure there's even the *concept* of a namespace at that point... nor would I expect it to be useful anyway.

I've just tried to reproduce this with the C# 2 compiler, and I can't see any trace of an empty namespace within the IL.

Answer (score 7):

The only semi-related issue I can think of is that when compiling a project in msbuild, indirect references are not always copied to the bin directory of the current app. If library B indirectly references library A and library C references B only, library A's output will not necessarily be copied to the bin folder when compiling library C. In the past, I've used a null field reference on a class to ensure that the dependency is explicit and the output is deployed properly. Maybe the original devs experienced something similar and this was their solution?

Comment: You might be correct about reasoning for it, in that the namespace is expected to be seen for a purpose: maybe by a tool or some obscure edge case in a test. Who knows. I wish the documentation stated why the namespace must exist just for the sake of it.